# Update certain key in hash

Tags: ruby, hash

I only want to update the date element in a hash.
i.e.

```
hash = { 'name': 'Albert', 'date_1': "31-01-2017", 'date_2': "31-01-2017" }

## I only want to update `date_1` and `date_2`.
```

I have tried

```
hash.select {|k,v| ['date_1','date_2'].include? k }.transform_values!(&:to_date)
```

but because I do a select before, it will only return me

`{ 'date_1': Tue, 31 Jan 2017, 'date_2': Tue, 31 Jan 2017 }`

Any suggestion to do keep other attributes as well as transform the selected key?

`i.e. { 'name': 'Albert', 'date_1': Tue, 31 Jan 2017, 'date_2': Tue, 31 Jan 2017 }`

Comment: Not just `hash['date_1'] = <new date>` for each key whose value is to be changed? To change the name of a key from (say) `:a` to `:b`: `hash[:b] = hash.delete(:a)` (as `delete` returns the value of `:a`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just update a value for date_1 and date_2:

```
hash['date_1'] = hash['date_1'].to_date if hash['date_1']
hash['date_2'] = hash['date_2'].to_date if hash['date_2']
```

or you can do it with `each` if you have more a date keys:

```
date_keys = [:date_1, :date_2]
hash.each do |k,v| 
  hash[k] = v.to_date if date_keys.include?(k)
end
```

Comment: It's much more efficient to iterate over the values in `date_keys`, rather than iterating over the entire hash. `date_keys.each { |key| hash[key] = hash[key].to_date if hash[key] }`.

Comment: Since the date_keys is a symbol, it should be `date_keys = [:date_1, :date_2]`

Answer (score 1):

If you want something a bit more dynamic, without having to hardcode `date_1` and `date_2` :

```
require 'date'
hash = { name: 'Albert', date_1: "31-01-2017", date_2: "31-01-2017" }

hash.each do |key, value|
  if key.to_s =~ /^date_/ && value.is_a?(String)
    hash[key] = Date.strptime(value, '%d-%m-%Y')
  end
end

p hash
#=> {:name=>"Albert", :date_1=>#<Date: 2017-01-31 ((2457785j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, :date_2=>#<Date: 2017-01-31 ((2457785j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>}
```

Note that for your code :

```
hash.select {|k,v| ['date_1','date_2'].include? k }.transform_values!(&:to_date)
```

`transform_values!` tries to modify a Hash in place which is only short-lived (the new hash returned by `select`). `transform_values` would achieve the exact same result.

Answer (score 0):

Quick dynamic way

```
hash = { 'name' => 'Albert', 'date_1' => "31-01-2017", 'date_2' => "31-01-2017" }

hash.map { |k,v| hash[k] = k['date_'] ? v.to_date : v }
```

Will work on any key that contains `date_`, like `date_02`, `date_1234`, `date_lastmonth`, etc